# Djikstra's algorithm for shortest path problems (undirected version?)

Tags: algorithms

When using Djikstra's algorithm, during each iteration, we pick a node $j$. Then, we look at all arcs $(i,j)$ where $i$ is not a "finished node", and determine if the distance from node $i$ needs updating or not.

But when picking an arc $(i,j)$, is this a directed arc, i.e. one which goes into node $j$? So what's the algorithm if there is no direction on the arcs, either on just some or all of them? I can't pick this up from the definition.

Comment: You could think of an undirected edge $\{a,b\}$ as a pair of arcs $(a,b)$ and $(b,a)$, and apply Dijkstra's algorithm in the usual way.  I don't recall ever seeing an undirected version of Dijkstra's algorithm.

Comment: If all the edges have positive length (weight), then a shortest path from a source node to a target will never visit any intermediate node more than once along a shortest path.  So Dijkstra's algorithm works perfectly well for undirected graphs (any candidate edge from a finished to unfinished node will only be considered in one direction anyway).

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing with an undirected graph, the arcs with no direction mean they can go both ways with the same weight.

Answer (score 1):

The Wikipedia description of [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Algorithm) (1959) makes no mention of edges as directed or undirected.

It is unnecessary to do so.  In updating the "tentative distance" of an unvisited (unfinished) node to the source, only the incoming edges (and their weights) of the unvisited node need to be considered.  In an undirected graph this is simply all the edges incident to that node.

In response to a recent Question about [non-optimality of Dijksta's algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1048446/is-dijkstras-algorithm-optimal-for-unweighted-graphs), an asymptotically better algorithm for *undirected graphs with positive integer weights* by Mikkel Thorup (1999) is referenced.  However this algorithm is much more difficult to implement and requires very large graphs to be competitive with Dijkstra's for the single source-single target shortest path problem.